# Print specified text if string is empty using AWK

Tags: string, awk

I am trying to print a particular text using `awk` if string is empty. It works fine in the below case

```
noob@noob:~$ echo "" | awk '{if ($0=="") print "not playing"}'
not playing
```

but when I try to take a similar approach in the below case it didn't work

```
noob@noob:~$ mpc current | awk '{if ($0=="") print "not playing"}'
noob@noob:~$
```

I believe the output of `mpc current` if no song is playing is an empty string.

```
noob@noob:~$ mpc current
noob@noob:~$              #empty string
```

So, is my assumption of `empty string`  wrong?

Comment: whats the result of `mpc current | awk '{print "X$0X"}'`

Comment: It prints `nothing`. It's output is same as `mpc current` I mentioned above.

Comment: `awk` processes 'lines'. If there is no output from `mpc current`, there is no line to process.

Comment: @Noob It was just to confirm that the output of mpc current was not " ", (ie a single space)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently it prints nothing at all, not even a newline.  Try this instead.

```
mpc current | awk '{ print } END { if (!NR) print "not playing" }'
```

This prints any output.  If you don't want that, take out the `{ print }`.

awk processes each line in turn, and then at EOF performs any END block. If there were no input lines, there will be an EOF right at the start, the variable `NR` will be zero, and so the END block will print the placeholder text. (I originally had a dedicated variable for this, but the built-in line number variable `NR`, as used in Bob Vale's answer, is decidedly more elegant.  It is incremented for each input line that `awk` reads.)

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly. Can you explain it to me what you did here.

Comment: Added an explanation, as suggested in an edit by @Karl Nordström.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
mpc current | awk 'END { if (NR==0) print "not playing"}'
```

Comment: you can add `{print}` before the END if you want to output the result

Answer (score 3):

Is this really a job for `awk`? Looks to me like the simple matter of line counting:

```
mpc current | if [[ $(wc -L) -eq 0 ]]; then echo "not playing"; fi
```

The above code counts the length of the longest line output by `mpc current`, and prints "`not playing`" if it is `0`.

Here is how it behaves:

```
$ echo ""       | if [[ $(wc -L) -eq 0 ]]; then echo "not playing"; fi
not playing
$

$ echo -n ""    | if [[ $(wc -L) -eq 0 ]]; then echo "not playing"; fi
not playing
$

$ echo "foo"    | if [[ $(wc -L) -eq 0 ]]; then echo "not playing"; fi
$

$ echo -n "foo" | if [[ $(wc -L) -eq 0 ]]; then echo "not playing"; fi
$
```

**OR**

As William Pursell says in their comment, you can also do:

```
mpc current | grep -q . || echo "not playing"
```

This doesn't require `bash` either.

Comment: of course this doesn't work if the OP wants it to print foo if the input is foo

Comment: @BobVale - The original snippet posted by the OP doesn't reproduce input. I assumed this is the required behavior. Plus, when writing a script, I would prefer a dependency on GNU coreutils over a dependency on GNU awk any day.

Comment: But why accept the `bash` dependency?  You can do this much more simply (and without requiring bash): `mpc current | grep -q . || echo "not playing"`  Notice that this makes it easy to satisfy Bob's criticism, since you can omit `-q`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - +1. That should be an answer. I'd appreciate if you write one. If not, I'll go ahead and edit it in. As to *why accept a `bash` dependency?*, I never thought about it. It's the only shell I use. You are right of course.

Comment: `grep .` doesn't count empty lines. If this makes a difference to you, try `grep '^'` instead. The `grep` approach is clearly better than the antipattern of counting the number of output lines.